# How to locate an unhandled exception

Tags: c++, exception

I am writing a program in c++11 using visual studio 2013.
When the program ends, meaning after it finishes the main, I get this exception:

> First-chance exception at 0x00EB1AC6 in prog.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.

What could cause this? I mean, there are no more lines of code...

EDIT: In debug, I am taken to this file : crtexe.c
and the exception occurs here: lines 648-649:

## ifndef _CRT_APP

```
            exit(mainret);
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: After main() _finishes_ many things will happen. Destructor will be called and memory freed, for example.

Comment: Could you at least give us the stack frames ? They will surely point at which function is the problem

Comment: Are you using threads?

Comment: After `main` ends, for each global object that you have in your code, the object's destructor is called. So the statement "there are no more lines of code" is basically wrong.

Comment: 0xFEEEFEEE means you are trying to access a memory that is already been freed by heap.

Comment: The destructor of one of your globals is trying to use something that has been deallocated.

Comment: Yes, I am using threads...

Answer (score 2):

In the Debug menu, select Exceptions. Tick everything. Rerun. Now it will trigger a breakpoint whenever an exception is first thrown.

Note that the error message suggests the exception WAS handled in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a destructor for a global or static object (or possibly other code that you registered with at_exit) that's referencing memory that's already been freed.

The clues are:

- The address `0xFEEEFEEE` is the fill pattern the debug version of the dynamic memory functions in MSVC++ uses to mark memory that's been freed.  So you think there's still a valid pointer in there, and you're accessing it.
- The crash happens after main returns, so it's likely a destructor or at_exit function.
- The order that destructors for static objects run is not completely defined in C++, so it's a common mistake to have one static object refer to another static object that's no longer around.  It's the inverse of the indeterminate construction order for static objects.

You can debug it by setting the debugger to break on the first-chance exception.  You'll almost certainly see which destructor is running on the stack when the crash happens.  You fix it by not depending on the order that static objects are destructed (or constructed).

Since you're multi-threaded, it could also be that your main thread has ended and some of your other threads are still accessing global objects.  (I don't think this is your problem because of where in the stack you are when it crashes, but I don't really have enough information to be sure.)  In general you have to prevent your main thread from ending before the worker threads (by joining threads before exiting the original thread), or you have to forcefully terminate the processes rather than letting the normal exit stuff happen.  Prefer the first option.